# Conditional inside of React Module

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, module

I have two adjacent React modules that adds/removes users from the other.  What is the best method of returning a notice if all the users have been removed from the "remove users" module.  For example, here is my module where users are removed:

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({

handleRemove: function () {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.user.id);
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="selected-user">
                <p onClick={this.handleRemove}>{this.props.user.first_name} {this.props.user.last_name}<i onClick={this.handleRemove} className="fa fa-close"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

So if there are no users inside of the "selected users" div, I would like to to return "you have not selected any users".  I am wondering what is the most efficient method of doing this inside of the module.

Answer (score 0):

You should be managing this logic within a higher order Component that encloses both of your adjacent components.

The Higher component should manage the `selectedUsers` as an array within its state.  It should pass this as props to both of the adjacent components you already have.

When modifying it's own state (or responding to a relevant action by the user), the Higher component should check if `selectedUsers` is an empty array.  If it is, it should fire off whatever action you wish to happen at that point.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this is well explained by the React documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

In your case the simplest way to do what you want will be to use ternary operators inside your JSX:

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            {some_condition ? <SomeComponent/> : <SomeOtherComponent/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will render `<SomeComponent/>` if the value of `some_condition` is truthy, or `<SomeOtherComponent/>` if it is not. Obviously adjust the condition and the components to match your code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are passing list of selected users to this component

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({

  renderUsers:function(){
   return this.props.selectedUsers.map(function(user){
         <li>{user}</li>
    }
 },
  render: function () {
   var selectedUsers = this.props.selectedUsers||[];
   var component= selectedUsers.length===0
                  ?<div> No users selected</div>
                  :this.renderUsers();

    return (
             <div>
                {component}
             </div>
     )


  }
});
```